# Change "help" to "about" in mobile application

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, ios-app

I use the Stack Exchange mobile app and I'd like to see one change to help end users out.

On the menu towards the bottom there is a "help" link, which is a bit misleading. There is no help at this link: this link is only version information about the app.

Change its text from help to about and either add a real help link that runs a tour of how Stack Exchange works just like the [Stack Overflow tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour).

Or eliminate "help" altogether and simply rename it to "about."

Comment: Great suggestion, we've had plans to add a help center in the app for a while but haven't yet and the current presentation of what we have is definitely misleading.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi - will this come in the form of an update via the play store?

Comment: This change has been done in iOS.

Comment: And the android app I see is still old :|.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the next update for both iOS and Android the "Help" item in the left sidebar is now labeled "About", thanks for the great suggestion!

Comment: Still not working as I had expected: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239827/mobile-app-about-link-still-incorrect