# Mobile app - About link still incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I posted this some time back: [Change "help" to "about" in mobile application](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238678/change-help-to-about-in-mobile-application)

I got the recent update and it is "About" which is perfect...But when you click on it the header of the page still says "Help".  This page has nothing to do with help and its only relevance is version information and about information.  There is no help section on this page so I believe its best to remove the wording as it serves no purpose.

Also can we get rid of the android guy with the stackexchange logo in it - it looks odd, those who have the app on the android device already know its an android application.

See screenshot:

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I missed that! I even tapped on it to make sure it still worked but I guess I ignored the title. As of the next update it'll simply say "About" -- I'm going to keep the android icon there for now though since I'm planning changing up that entire page soon anyway.